# Page not redirecting properly 3

Tags: php, authentication

I have the following code to re-direct users to their rightfull pages. However, I am getting an error in the browser:

Error:

> The page is not re-directing correctly

The code:

```
<?php
/**
 * User has already logged in, so display relevant links, including
 * a link to the admin center if the user is an administrator.
 */

    if (($session->logged_in) && ($session->isAgent())) {

        header("Location: gallery_Agent.php");

} elseif (($session->logged_in) && ($session->isMaster())) {

        header("Location: gallery_Master.php");

} elseif (($session->logged_in) && ($session->isAdmin())) {     

        header("Location: gallery_Admin.php");

} 

else {  ...
```

How may I fix this?

Joseph

Comment: Try to use absolute URL maybe

Answer (score 1):

This error usually indicates an infinite redirect loop. Always use `exit()` after setting the `Location` header, and make sure you're not including this redirect logic in the pages you're redirecting to.